# Fetching Youtube videos with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, youtube-api

I need to find a way to fetch a Youtube JSON url and print the titles and descriptions. The code I have here succeeds when I try to fetch, but the array it receives is empty when I try to see it in console.

Do you know why this may happen?

You can find the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BHrmC/73/

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend();

var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item,

    url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/67DEB98D8D9CF0F7?v=2&alt=json-in-script&max-results=6",

    parse: function(response) {
        return response.results;
    },

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        var that = this;
        var params = _.extend({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: that.url,
            processData: false
        }, options);

        return $.ajax(params);
    }
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#test'),
    events: {
        'click button#add': 'getPost'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'getPost');
        this.collection = new List();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>get</button>");
    },
    getPost: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(that.collection.toJSON());
                console.log("working");
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Failed to fetch!');
            }

        });
    }
});

// **listView instance**: Instantiate main app view.
var listView = new ListView();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make up your mind on the data representation you want to use. The code shown here uses an XML to JSON conversion (`alt=json-in-script`) while the URL in you Fiddle points to a much simpler representation, a JSON-C feed (`alt=jsonc`). See https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc#Comparing_JSON_and_JSONC for more info.
2. Assuming you meant to use a JSON-C representation, the items definitions are under `data.items`

   ```
   parse: function(response) {
       return response.data.items;
   }
   ```
3. The video data for each object is under a *video* attribute. Assuming you want your `Item` instances to directly reflect the videos, you will have to unwrap them with [_.pluck](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#pluck) for example:

   ```
   parse: function(response) {
       var items = response.data.items;
       return _.pluck(items, 'video');
   }
   ```

And an updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BHrmC/80/